# Android: I try to replace one fragment with another, but it overlaps them

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I'm trying to replace a `fragment` 1 with a `Fragment` 2 on button click, but the fragment doesn't get replaced, it sits on top.

the content of both Fragments remain on the screen, what am I doing wrong? What I can do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M8TkQ.png)

**this is the class of fragment 1**

```
public class Login extends Fragment {

Button btn_login;

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

public Login() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment Login.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static Login newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    Login fragment = new Login();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    btn_login = vista.findViewById(R.id.btn_login);

    btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            // Create new fragment and transaction
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment
            transaction.replace(R.id.layout_login,fragment_menu_seleccion.newInstance("",""));
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);



            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
        }
    });

    return vista;
}
```

**this is the class of fragment 2**

```
public class fragment_menu_seleccion extends Fragment {

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

public fragment_menu_seleccion() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment fragment_menu_seleccion.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static fragment_menu_seleccion newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    fragment_menu_seleccion fragment = new fragment_menu_seleccion();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu_seleccion, container, false);
}}
```

**The xml of Fragment 1**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".Controlador.Login"
>

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_login"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#219EBC"
    >


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/txtBinvenidaLogin"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#B3ffffff"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtTitle2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:text="@string/txtBinvenidaLogin2"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/txtTitle1" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cardbox"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="-39dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="274dp"
                android:layout_height="116dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/dscriptIMGlogin"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/heuristictool1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/titleLogin"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="@font/roboto_mono_medium"
                android:text="@string/TextoMobile"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="User"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editTextTextPassword"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_login"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="67dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:onClick="Login"
            android:text="@string/btnLogin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**The xml of Fragment 2**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragment_menu_seleccion">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="This a Fragment 2" />

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
        android:id="@+id/grupoFAB"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-8dp"
        app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/Ui_colorContraste"
        >
        <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.AddFloatingActionButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/btn_crearEV"
            app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/Ui_colorContraste"
            app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_icon_lapiz"

            />


    </com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>


</RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

To hide the content below in the fragments, you must give it a background like white. So, in your layout files, in the root layout, set its background to white.

```xml
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

or

```xml
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
```